# Можно ли обьеденить protocol - ы в swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Поскольку `protocol`-ы в swift то же самое, что и `interface` в `java` у меня возник вопрос, можно ли как то объединить `protocol` , чтоб было похоже на вот так как тут:

```
interface DataTable { 
    interface View {
    }

    interface Listener {
    }
}
```

в Swift я не могу сделать то же с протоколами... Мне нужно создавать отдельные файлы

Если не правильно объяснил, спрашивайте

В общем вот такая проблема

Answer (score 0):

Возможно отсутсвтие вложенности сделано для упрощения. По поводу написания можно просто в одном файле объединить протоколы:

```
protocol Protocol1 {
}

protocol Protocol2 {   
}
```

---

Для подобной организации Вы можете использовать `typealias`-ы:

```
protocol DataTableView {
}

protocol DataTableListener {
}

enum DataTable {
    typealias View = DataTableView
    typealias Listener = DataTableListener
}

///И используем:
class ViewController: UIViewController, DataTable.Listener
```

Comment: Ну это да, но в примере с java мне кажется это удобно в том плане что когда общаются `View` и `Controller` через `interface`  , то удобно что один интерфейс обьеденяет в себе одни методы для `Controller` другие для обратной связи с `View`

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko , обновил ответ :)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать композицию протоколов:

```
protocol ProtocolFirst {
    var first: String { get }
}
protocol ProtocolSecond {
    var second: Int { get }
}
struct BothProtocols: ProtocolFirst, ProtocolSecond {
    var first: String
    var second: Int
}
```

*в дальнейшем используйте структуру BothProtocols, как тип, соответстующий указанным протоколам*